# Getting Paypal Return string into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

```
public function run()
    {
        $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            $postFields .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $fh = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $result . ' -- ' . $postFields);
        fclose($fh);

        echo $result;
    }
}
?>
```

I get the result in a text file like so:

?cmd=_notify-validate&test_ipn=1&payment_type=instant&payment_date=02:39:41 Oct 06, 2011 PDT&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John Smith&address_country=United States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San Jose&address_street=123, any street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=TESTSELLERID1&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=9.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=41106939¬ify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&charset=windows-1252&verify_sign=AB3bSjvFd3wXL7rCt.OOGW-nSKg-Ahh5RbboVG4bn9LSAon94Wjt2Oj9

How do I decode this string and put it into mysql database?

I need the customer first name, last name, address,email, item number, item name, quantity, shipping, and timestamp put into the database. Please I have come this far in the code, I just need help decoding it and getting it into the database. Thanks

Comment: Your file only seems to contain the post fields, where is the result?

Comment: The result is the string you see above, I capture it in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to decode the string.

I just checked the PayPal documentation. The only thing that `notify-validate` returns is a string `VERIFIED` or `INVALID`. None of the stuff you posted is part of the PayPal return string. If you want the last name, it's in `$_POST['last_name']`.

To get it into a mysql INSERT statement, do something like this (I'm just showing 4 columns, you can extrapolate to all the fields you want):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (first_name, last_name, address, email) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I know sql code, I just dont know how to get the array into msysql insert statement.

Comment: I've added some code to show that, it assumes you're using the mysqli API. If you use PDO, the translation should be obvious. If you're using the mysql extension, upgrade.

Comment: You are right the notify-validate returns verified or invalid. I get the result of send IPN from paypal into the text file. Some fields from that string is what i want in the database. I understand the sql statement. The question is how do i get for example last_name from the string even before the txt file is involved build an array then take  the result and put it in the database? what comes before "$stmt = $con->prepare" ?

Comment: You don't get it from the string. The string came from `$_POST`. So just get it from `$_POST`.

Comment: Are you doing this in a different script from the one that sent the command to PayPal? Is that why you need to use the file? I suggest you  write `json_encode($_POST)` to the file, rather than the query string. Then use `json_decode()` to translate it back into an array.

Comment: oh! my bad! what is "ssss" by the way? thanks for all your help you are awesome!

Comment: `"ssss"` is the types of the parameters. s = string, i = integer, f = float. See the mysqli documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
parse_str($string,$array);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the string with & to get each parameter with its value and then you can explode with = to get the key and the value.

```
$params = explode('&', $result);

$paypal_result_arr = array();

foreach($params AS $param) {
   $param_arr = explode('=', $param);

   if(count($param_arr) == 2) {
       $paypal_result_arr[$param_arr[0]] = $param_arr[1];
   }
}
```

$paypal_result_arr associative array will give you all values returned from paypal. 
After that you can get the first name using code $paypal_result_arr['first_name'] and so on...

Comment: That doesn't decode special characters in the query string, like %hex codes. That's why you should use a function like `parse_str`.